# why do I get an error in react-toastify module?

Tags: reactjs, react-toastify

I'm using react-toastify to pop up an error message. Why do I get this error?

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
> useToastContainer
> E:/Courses/programing/Code with Mosh/Front End/Mastering React/08 - Calling Backend Services (01h42m)/Section 8- Calling Backend Services/start/http-app/node_modules/react-toastify/dist/react-toastify.esm.js:866

[image: error]

Once I remove `ToastContainer` component everything works normally. What should I do to get rid of this error, and why do I get it?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible sandbox?

Comment: I attached a screen of the error that I get  here it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMnxu.png

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new here in StackOverflow I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem here, I guess we are both using the newest version of react-toastify, but after I change the version with 4.1 (which the instructor is using) and it solved !

First, you need  :

> npm uninstall react-toastify --save

Then, reinstall it with the version 4.1

> npm i react-toastify@4.1

Comment: I also needed to restart my development server to changes take effect

Answer (score 1):

Building on Pelic's answer, after uninstalling the latest version and reinstalling version 4.1, i had to restart my VSCode to get it to work!